Higher capacitance for EMI return cap in isolated DC-DC-SMPS?
A typical SMPS converter usually includes a small capacitor of ~1 nF in tight proximity to the isolation transformer to return the common-mode switch noise to the primary side switch for EMC reasons.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The value of this capacitor is often in the range of 100 pF to 1 nF for small power supplies that have small parasitic capacitance through the transformer.
In a project, I already have larger 22 nF X7R caps in the BOM, that have sufficient voltage rating for the isolation requirements. Package size is also similar.
Is there any disadvantage (other than component cost) in using a capacitor in this role whose capacitance is not only much larger than the transformer's, but whose capacitance absolutely dwarfs the transformer capacitance? I know that you want to keep them small in offline AC/DC converters to limit mains leakage current, but this question is about DC/DC converters.

What is the isolation requirement? Is it purely DC/galvanic (and I guess, low voltage)? Or is there any AC involved? The CM impedance introduced by the capacitor is a strong consideration in many circuits (mains leakage being an applied case).

@TimWilliams yes it is about galvanic isolation. The secondary is a slow capacitor charging circuit that shall be isolated from the main circuit, which is a single 12 V ground referenced circuit

Depends on the application and target standards. I'll mention some disadvantages based on some assumptions.

In off-mains applications that capacitor is a Y-cap which is designed to fail open in order to maintain the isolation and keep the shock risk low in case of a failure. An X7R will quite possibly go fail short so the isolation will be lost in the same case. It's unclear if this is acceptable in your application or the target standard(s).

Having a larger cap will ensure a smaller potential difference between the grounds at high frequencies but also will increase the leakage between the primary and the secondary. It's unclear if the capacitor is MLCC or single layer, but with higher leakage current the vibration inside the cap therefore the risk of having an audible noise may increase.

It's unclear if your application is subject to any hi-pot/flash test. During the test a voltage (AC or DC) is applied across shorted pri and shorted sec terminals for some time (e.g. 1 minute), and the current flowing through is measured. If it exceeds the threshold it'll be a FAIL. If the test voltage is DC then the unit may not fail, but if the test voltage is AC then the leakage current will effectively be higher with 22 nF so the unit may fail the test.


